# Looping through child elements of getElementsByClassName nodelist. Can't get it to work properly

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, foreach, nodelist

I have a webpage with a series of dynamically rendered images that I want to target and change their src attribute with a script, depending on some other logic. I do not have access to their specific markup, but wrapped each one in a div element with the classname "siteavatar".

I am trying to loop through each .siteavatar element and then target their child image element.

I have placed the following code at the bottom of my footer, right before the closing body tag (so placement in the DOM timeline shouldn't be an issue):

```
    <script>
   
    window.onload = function() {
        var siteAvatars = document.getElementsByClassName("siteavatar");
      console.log(siteAvatars);
     
      siteAvatars.forEach(function(siteAvatar){
          console.log(siteAvatar.querySelector(".avatar"));
      });
    }
    
</script>
```

The console will succesfully log the siteAvatars variable, but nothing I do will get it to recognize the loop. I have tried multiple different approaches, such as siteAvatar.children, etc.

I have also tried a more regular for loop, with no success:

```
<script>

window.onload = function() {
    var siteAvatars = document.getElementsByClassName("siteavatar");
   
   for (var i = 0; i < siteAvatars.length; i++) {
       console.log(siteAvatars[i].children)
   }
  console.log(siteAvatars);
}
```

The problem seems to be looping through the siteAvatars nodelist itself; if I switch the console.log to siteAvatars[i].style.display = "none" / siteAvatar.style.display = "none" , that does not work either.

It seems to me there is something obvious I am missing that is outside the scope of what I am troubleshooting on. Any ideas of what it might be? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a for loop. Use `querySelector` to get the child element.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var siteAvatars = document.getElementsByClassName("siteavatar");
  var numSiteAvatars = siteAvatars.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < numSiteAvatars; i++) {
    var sa = siteAvatars[i];
    var a = sa.querySelector(".avatar");
    console.log(a);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="siteavatar">
  <img src="" class="avatar" />
</div>
<div class="siteavatar">
  <img src="" class="avatar" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dan. This isn't working on my site for some strange reason. It looks like siteAvatars.length is returning 0 (despite a list showing up in the console if logged). Not sure why that might be, but it seems to be the core issue.

Comment: It's possible they are being added after the actual load event has fired. You could set the function to run on a timeout so that you give it a few seconds after the load event to search for them.